# pc having no system sound

Tags: windows-7, audio

so i have dell PC. i can't hear any sound, when i check in sound mixer while playing a video, the green line thingy is there for google chrome and digital audio but nothing coming from system sound. can anyone help? :( also only change made was yesterday we went from windows 10 back to 7 but it was fixed at another persons house so we had to plug it in again at my home.I already tried few methods like going in system and making sure everything's on but that didn't really help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: *we went from windows 10 back to 7* this will do it. Windows 7 has no support for modern hardware and will never have because it's out of support and dangerous if used online. This is the single dumbest mode anyone can do - moving from a supported OS to an obsolete one -, expect a LOT more problem down the road.

Comment: We had windows 7 before 10 and it still worked...

Comment: @changan perhaps you could explain how 7 is "dangerous if used online"?

Comment: Certainly: https://www.business2community.com/tech-gadgets/top-5-risks-of-using-outdated-software-in-your-company-02412185

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel - Sound

Make certain to select the sound drivers you have installed, so your OS recognizes them.

Alternatively, go to dxdiag in your start menu search bar to open DirectX utility and diagnose your sound issue from the selection tabs.

Answer (score -1):

Probably something to do with the sound drivers. Can you delete them and restart your PC? Go to device manager and under sound find the current driver and delete it. On restart, Windows should automatically reinstall it.

Comment: I tried that and didn't work, do you have any other idea what I could try?

Comment: "A dell PC" doesn't really narrow anything down. Find out what your specific hardware (sound card/chip/controller) is and download and install the manufacturer's driver for it.